# Understanding the for-loop

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

I have a Little problem understanding something about the for loop. In the code i post below. Shouldn't it print out two stars then line break, then two stars and line break etc? Because the code first checks if "i" is less than or equal to 5, if not it checks if "j" is less or equal to 10. Then it prints out "*" and then a line break.

BUT it seems like it first checks the first condition, then skips to `println("*")` and then skips the line break. Why do it skip?

```
public class Printing {
    public static void main( String[] args ){
        for ( int i = 1; i <= 5; i++ ){
            for ( int j = 1; j <= 10; j++ )
                System.out.print( "*" );
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You would understand it better if you indented the code.

Comment: And put opening and closing braces for each loop.

Comment: If you want 2 starts then change j<=10 to j<=2

Comment: THe trick that's confusing you here is that it is legal syntax (but poor form) to follow a for loop by a single statement instead of a loop.  so that first `System.out.print("*");` is the entire block that will be executed by the "inner" for loop (the one with `j` as the control variable)

Comment: I swear I've seen this exact question so many times on this site and every time the inner for loop is missing `{}`

Comment: @JGrice That's why some languages force you to use braces (like Go), or proper indentation (Python). Unfortunately, that's not the case in Java.

Comment: The question is copied direcly from an old exam. The question is written excacly that way and the question is "What does this code print out".

Answer (score 1):

Your nested `for` loop will print 10 sequences of `"*"`.

Your outer `for` loop repeats your nested `for` loop followed by printing a line break 5 times.

The issue you may have is with the curly brackets not surrounding your nested `for` loop.

As such, the `"*"` is printed 5 * 10 times, but the line break is printed only 5 times, because it pertains to the scope of the **outer** `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

Your for loop is nested. That means that second for loop is *inside* the first one. So if the condition for the first one doesn't pass, the second one wouldn't even run.

Answer (score 0):

"the code first checks if "i" is less than or equal to 5, if
not it checks if "j" is less or equal to 10."

No. If `i` is not less than or equal to 5,the whole body of the `for` loop will not get executed and as the inner loop is inside the body of the outer one,it will also not get executed.

Your code will print 5 rows each having 10 `*`.